Is light emited from fluorescent material coherent and monochromatic?
Does fluorescent material (like Fluorescein excited with UV light) produce coherent and monochromatic light? If yes, can a laser created with fluorescent material?

Normally an optically active medium is only a part of a laser. Why do you expect any material alone to produce coherent and monochromatic light?

Fluorescence is not a key requirement for a laser active material. Key is population inversion, i.e. specific energy level system within material scheme, usually with many virtual upper levels, which traps as more electrons as possible, waiting to be released by stimulated emission.

A fluorescent material is just a light. It is not coherent. It emits spectral lines that are fairly monochromatic. It may become a laser when it is put in an optical cavity. As @AgniusVasiliauskas says, population inversion is key. See Question about lasers

Actually my question is not very well formulated due to lack of physics knowledge and how laser works.
What I actually wanted to know, was if fluorescent material can be used as lasing medium. As stated in the comments, it's not monochromatic on it's own.
The answer is yes for Florescein it can be used as seen on Wikipedia Dye Laser page

Don't feel bad about the down votes. This is not a bad question. There is a lot to laser physics. Laser light is not perfectly monochromatic either. It does produce a narrower range of wavelengths that most light sources. Also fluorescent lights (aka gas discharge) are commonly used in lasers. The very common HeNe laser uses a neon light with some helium added.
